# Eclipse Docker Tooling command-line run options

Tags: eclipse, docker

[image: Screen Shot]

I am using Eclipse docker tooling (version 5.1.0.202012081929). Is there any way to specify docker options, for instance `-w /usr/src/mymaven`   or `-p 8080:8080`?   The first example is an option missing from the dialog, while the second would help debug or override what may not be working from the dialog.

Comment: What dialog are you referring to? A screenshot would help.

Comment: I attached a screen shot.  Thanks!